# ManyToOne doing multiple queries to fetch records

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have two entities, and `dept_id` is the foreign key here.

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
  ...
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private Integer id; 

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
  private Department department;
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class Department implements Serializable {
  ...
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private Integer id; 

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

Now I am doing the following JPQL where I have around 100 parameters inside `in` query:

```
select o from Student o where o.id in(1,2,7,9,15,16, ...)
```

When I see the JPA log, I found it is fetching 100 records from the `Student` by one query. After that it is doing 100 separate queries to fetch the `Department` for each `Student`. So far my understanding is the I/O operation should be slow. Is there any way so that it fetches everything by a single query?

Comment: and you have tried "FETCH JOIN" on student.department?

Comment: I just tried `query.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "o.department");` and I think I can progress further with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this worked for me:

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "o.department");
```

Also, I found this one is handy as it does not make any joining, but fetches the records separately in a bulk.

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.batch", "o.department");
```